# Does anyone know why my custom CSS styling for links does not show up on safari?

Tags: html, css, squarespace, text-decorations

I am using custom css for my squarespace site and the text decoration I set up shows up fine on Chrome but for some reason doesn't seem to be activated on safari? Code below

```
//HYPERLINK STYLING//
p a, h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, 
{
text-decoration: white dotted underline;
text-decoration-thickness:1px;
text-underline-offset: 0.25em;
}

a:hover 
{text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

body.site-title .logo a
{text-decoration: none;
}
```

I was hoping that this simple bit of text styling would work across all platforms.. but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: What happens if you use `a:link` instead of just `a`?

Comment: Safari is a bit behind compared to other browsers in terms of css specifically. You can check if safari supports some props using https://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not support a few attributes of [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration#browser_compatibility), so you need to have a prefix `-web-kit-` for them

```
//HYPERLINK STYLING//
p a, h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, 
{
  text-decoration: white dotted underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration: white dotted underline;
  text-decoration-thickness:1px;
  text-underline-offset: 0.25em;
}

a:hover 
{
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

body.site-title .logo a
{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```